# /review queue - Duplicate automatic comments

Tags: bug, review

Spotted a minor flaw in the new `/review` system -- If multiple (non-moderator) users select the same automatic comment for a question it gets posted multiple times.

This can give the appearance that we're beating up on the user as they accumulate a stream of auto-comments telling them *exactly the same thing*

One example from SF:
[image]
Original question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/450938/documentation-on-processes-related-to-servers-storage-networking-user-managem).

There are two copies of the `While this link may answer . . .` link-only auto comment.

---

Possible fix: When using an auto-comment, scan comments for exact matches before posting
  (could be a fast checksum).

Comment: I'm almost positive it already does this, maybe it fails if there are other comments between?  Or something else unique about this post, I know I've picked from the list a comment that was already listed, and it simply give it an upvote rather than reposting it.

Comment: When the exact same comment already exists, it's *supposed* to just automatically upvote the existing comment, to indicate your agreement with the existing one.

Comment: @KDiTraglia It's possible the intermediate comments are messing it up - I vaguely recall the upvote behavior but wasn't sure if *I* was doing it or it was happening automatically...

Comment: Perhaps the user went in and edited the auto-generated comment (and either didn't change anything, reverted a change he made, or changed something we can't see from the image), and because of that it choose to not upvote it but add a new comment?

Comment: I also have seen duplicate comments with or without other comments in between.

Comment: @Servy the comments are character-for-character identical, but the first one has an upvote -- Perhaps that confused it...

Comment: @voretaq7 The upvote shouldn't be a problem, based on my past experiences.  As I said, it's possible the user edited the comment then edited it again to reverse the comment.  It's unlikely, but possible.

Comment: I for one think it's a good way for the answer to keep track of how many people are recommending his question to be deleted and why

Comment: @Sam, then maybe the original comment should be updated with a counter instead of being duplicated. It would be easier on the eyes.